# How to disable suspending the system when the lid is closed?

Tags: suspend, sway

How can I disable suspending when the lid is closes?

I never suspend my laptop. When I close the lid and the system is running, I want the screen to be blanked, but the system should run as if the lid was open.

How can I achieve this in Sway?

Comment: Did you check the power management options? This is usually where [this thing is managed](https://imgur.com/PcocRwH) (screenshot is for KDE...).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure Sway handles that, so first try disabling system-wide lid actions by editing `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and see if it works (you can also use `lock` instead of `ignore`):

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
```

`sudo systemctl kill -s HUP systemd-logind` - will apply these changes.